# What does this notification icon mean? Samsung s7

Tags: google-play-store, 5.0-lollipop, samsung, 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s7

I just bought an galaxy s7 edge, and this weird icon is on my notifcation bar. I cannot seem to figure it out.  Does anyone know what it does or means? Thanks. [image: samsung screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be related to the [joyn service](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joyn). (This link goes to the german Wikipedia page, as the logo is not visible on the [english version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Communication_Services)).

Joyn (or RCS - Rich Communication Services) is meant to be a new messaging standard, created by service providers as a response to messaging services like WhatsApp.

Comment: How do you take it off? Why would I have a German app notifcation on my phone?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with these questions - but you might ask your network carrier, they should know ;-)