# Help Identifying Statusbar Icon

Tags: notification-icons

Is anybody able to tell me what this supernova looking icon in between the bluetooth and wifi icon is?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Check this question: [What does this notification icon mean? Samsung s7](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/158520/what-does-this-notification-icon-mean-samsung-s7)

Comment: Solved. Thanks guys! Link: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/158520/what-does-this-notification-icon-mean-samsung-s7

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings** -> **Notification center** -> **Status bar icons** 
there the all icons for your status bar will appear. Find what it is.